# Is there an easy way to compare if 2 XDocuments are equal ignoring element/attribute order?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Unit testing my serialization code I found one failed because I had attributes listed in a different order (I'm just comparing the XDocument.ToString() values) and while I could fix that, it really doesn't matter to me in what order the elements or attributes appear as long as they're all there with the right name at the right level of hierarchy.  I could probably write a method do this, but I'm wondering if there's an easy built in way I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 12):

XNode has a DeepEquals function that should do the trick.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.deepequals.aspx

Update:

It appears that the DeepEquals function doesn't always work correctly. You may be best off implementing your own comparison routine.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=400469

Comment: DeepEquals works like charm for me. Thanks.
I have read the post mentioned by Aim Kai, and luckily those scenarios weren't applicable in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Microsoft XML Diff and patch utility [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx)
or google "Xml Diff"