# How to compare 2 web.configs by content in C# using powershell?

Tags: c#, powershell, web-config

I want to compare 2 web.config files by content, so that the difference is shown in terms of line number. I don't want to use Compare-Object as it compares line by line, which is not exactly the proper method for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [XmlDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302295.aspx) can help.  It understands XML and generates a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to [Serialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx) the config files? You can even generate classes with [xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use the objects in your program as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for compare two web.config it means you wants two xml files, so you have to think that

You can use Xdocument object, Initialize two diffrunt XDocument object and load both xml respectivly

ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875625/is-there-an-easy-way-to-compare-if-2-xdocuments-are-equal-ignoring-element-attri) answer

Comment: How do I convert web.config files to XDocument objects? I have to generate an xml tree to use Deepequals right ?

Comment: web config itself a xml file parse it ti xdocument, ref how to pass xml to xdocument and follow it

Comment: Thanks..It helped..
But how do I find the line number or the particular tag in which change is there ?